# How to call a Lua function from Python?

Tags: python, lua, interop

I would like to know if there is any way we can call a function written in *Lua* from *Python* code. If so, could you please suggest me the best possible way to do the same?

Basically, I have 2 different modules one is written in *Lua* and other in *Python* and wanted to use them as it is without rewriting *Lua* module into *Python*.

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#Lua